# Visualize percentage in Kibana

Tags: kibana, kibana-4

I'm new to Kibana and want to create a visualization that shows percentage of unsuccessful events over time as a line chart.

I log an event for each of the cases: “Event success” and “Event error”.

Currently I have the two metrics in a single graph, but I don’t know how to calculate the percentage of unsuccessful events, i.e. count(“Event error”) / (count(“Event success”) + count(“Event error”)). Any ideas?

Kibana version: 4.1.1

Answer (score 5):

We wrote a plugin for this.
https://github.com/outbrain/ob-kb-percent
All you need to do is to install this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can go through the plugin, but sometimes there are issues in installing the plugin as it throws an error "No valid URL specified!".

Also for your this query you can try to access visual builder and calculate your unsuccessful events. Under data option in the visual builder, you can have math aggregation and try to perform your calculation.

Try this once, because this will give you graph visualization.